# Having trouble dealing with similar characters to print different things using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have single letters b, c, d.... that I substituted for random words using a dictionary and re.sub and multiple_replace function from regex library.  So, b = book, c= cook, 
d= dook, etc..

However, if there is a repeat of bb, cc, or dd... I want to be able to have those letters print out something else instead where all the double letters are equivalent to a single word like bb= blah, cc = blah, dd= blah followed by their letter. So bb=blahb, cc=blahc, dd=blahd.

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
print multiple_replace(dict, re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1', r'science\1', text,   flags = re.I))
```

where dict is the dictionary containing the words b= book, c= cook, d=dook, etc..

and re.sub function includes all double letters except vowels to be replaced with the word science plus their letter. The text represents my input string that I want to be converted to the string replacements found inside the dictionary.

So, I want the output to be bb =scienceb, cc=sciencec but the problem I'm currently having is that instead of printing the string "science" I want. It prints out the string replacements of the word science found inside the dictionary. So, e.g. 
    "s" : "sook", 
    "c" : "cook",
    "i" : "i",
    "n" : "nook",

so it prints out any double letter word it would replace it with sookcookiecooknooke  in my text string. Why is that? How can I fix it?

If I'm being confusing, please let me know. Thank you so much!

EDIT:

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import re 

def multiple_replace(dict, text): 
    # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text) 


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    text = "This is my first regex python example yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd"

    dict = {
        "a" : "a", 
        "b" : "book",
        "c" : "cook",
        "d" : "dook",
        "e" : "e", 
        "f" : "fook",
        "g" : "gook",
        "h" : "hook",
        "i" : "i",
        "j" : "jook", 
        "k" : "kook",
        "l" : "look",
        "m" : "mook",
        "n" : "nook",
        "o" : "o",
        "p" : "pook",
        "q" : "qook",
        "r" : "rook",
        "s" : "sook",
        "t" : "took",
        "u" : "u",
        "v" : "vook",
        "w" : "wook",
        "x" : "xook",
        "y" : "yook",
        "z" : "zook",
    } 


    print multiple_replace(dict, re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1', r'science\1', text, flags = re.I))
```

Comment: Could you give a complete working example with your actual output and expected output? I'm finding it a little hard to follow your description.

Comment: What is your expected output for `bbbbb`? Let's say single letter `b` is replaced by `re`.

Comment: Well here's the thing...b=re, okay that's fine. However, I want bb to equal to something else. eg. bb=science. so the expected output for bbbbb, would be sciencescienceb where bb would be replaced by science and b would be the last letter to indicate there was a double b preceding it. In the case you presented, re would not be used at all. Only if I had a word like "base", it would read like "rease" where b=re.

Comment: @Weeble, I added the code in the post. See the edit. My output is: Thookisook isook mookyook fookirooksooktook rookegookexook pookyooktookhookonook
 exookamookpooklooke yookahookooa yookahookoouuee sookcookienookcookebookbookiir
ooksookcookienookcookedook but for the output for the word bbbiirdd,I want it to be sciencebbookiirookscienced

Comment: @Euridice01: Your requirement is very confusing. If you don't understand your requirement enough to write a very detailed description, then I suggest that you sit back and think of all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code replaces the double letters in `text` with `"science"` and the letter, then passes the string to `multiple_replace` which then replaces each single letter - including the letters in `"science"` - with its corresponding dictionary value.

A better method to make the replacements would be to pass a callback to `sub` and to use a regex that matched double or single letters. The callback would determine what had been matched and return the corresponding replacement.

If you want to persist with the code you already have, a quick way of preventing the letters in `"science"` being replaced is to change the regex in `multiple_replace` to

```
regex = re.compile("science|(?<!science)(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
```

and add `"science" : "science",` to the `dict`.

This will mean `"science"` is replaced with `"science"`, and the negative look-behind `(?<!science)` will prevent the letter following it from being replaced.

The above though is not a good solution to your problem. If you are lucky someone more familiar with python than I am will offer a better one.

*Further to comments, and adapting eyquem's solution*

```
import re

def multiple_replace(dict, text):

    def repl(match):
        single, double = match.groups()
        if double:
            return 'science' + single
        else:
            return dict[single] if single in dict else single

    return re.sub(r'([bcdfghj-np-tv-z])(\1)?', repl, text, flags=re.I)    

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    text = "This is my d's first try at cing, yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd"   
    dict = { "b" : "blah", "c" : "cook", "d" : "dog" }   

    print multiple_replace(dict, text)
    # This is my dog's first try at cooking, yahooa yahoouuee sciencebblahiirscienced
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! That actually makes sense (doi!) but yeah it's not the best solution but it is _a_ solution. Thank you so much :D

Comment: How do you know it is `science` from the original string or `science` from the earlier replacement? Take `sscience` as input as an example.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Yes, that may be considered a limitation.

Comment: When I was informed of a new answer, I was just working on the type of solution described by MikeM. At this time, I was on the point to post my answer in the very next minutes. However, the MikeM's answer had been posted many minutes earlier - Before recently, I believed that someone was instantly informed when a new answer would come in the thread, but I had some experiences recently showing me that's not the case. I am right, am I not ? - However, during the following minutes after a question has been posted, it seems to me that the info of a new answer is received more instantly. y/n ?

Comment: @eyquem. Yes, we are not informed instantly of new answers.

Comment: @MikeM Except in the first minutes after a question have been posted ?

Comment: @MikeM OK, thanks . BTW i vote for your answer, since it has the principle of solution.

Answer (score 2):

The output for `"This is my first ...` must not be
`` Thookisook isook mookyook fookirooksooktook`... `` as you wrote,
but `Tookhookisook isook mookyook fookirooksooktook  ...`

The following code does the job according to your explanations.
There is no need of a dictionary.

```
import re 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def repl(ma):
        g1,g2 = ma.groups()
        if g2:
            return 'science' + g2
        else:
            return g1 + 'ook'


    print '------------ 1 ----------------------'
    text = "This is my first regex python example yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd"
    print text,'\n'
    wanted = ('Tookhookisook isook mookyook fookirooksooktook '
              'rookegookexook pookyooktookhookonook exookamookpooklooke '
              'yookahookooa '
              'yookahookoouuee '
              'sciencebbookiirookscienced')
    print 'wanted == %s' % wanted

    res = re.sub(r'([bcdfghj-np-tv-z])(\1?)',
                 repl,
                 text,
                 flags = re.I)
    print '\nres == %s' % res
    print 'res==wanted  : ',res==wanted

    print '------------ 2 ----------------------'
    print 'bbbiirdd'
    wanted = 'sciencebbookiirookscienced'
    print 'wanted == %s' % wanted
    res = re.sub(r'([bcdfghj-np-tv-z])(\1?)',
                                  repl,
                                  'bbbiirdd',
                                  flags = re.I)
    print '\nres == %s' % res
    print 'res==wanted  : ',res==wanted
```

Comment: +1 Looks good to me. I changed "waited " to "wanted" as I think that's what you meant.

Comment: Thank you to have corrected. In french, for such a case, it is said ``attendu``, from the verb ``s'attendre à`` which means ``to expect``. But I confused with the verb ``attendre`` meaning more specifically ``to wait``.

Comment: For a French, the word **wanted** is special, it evokes sinister faces of outlaws on pinned annoucement sheet at the time of the Far West because it is only in films and comics that we meet it. So I unconsciously didn't .. want to use it and I did a mistake

Comment: Thanks for this solution. What if the words didn't all end in ook? Like if b = blah, c= cook, =dog... Could I still use m.group? where m is a string input? At that point, I would have to use a dictionary right?

Comment: It seems you have difficulty wth english. I suppose it's not _" What if the words didn't all end in ook?"_ but _" What if I WANT each letter to be replaced with a word dependant of this letter?"_ It makes difficult to understand you. - Well, if so, the solution is to craft the function ``ripl()`` differently. Any solution a little complex in any kind is based on this kind of drawback. And yes, sure, you must use a dictionary.

Comment: You just have to define a dictionary ``d = dict(b='blah',c='core',d='diet',e='ear',...etc)`` and to pass it as argument by default to the function ``ripl(ma, d =d)``. Then when ``g2`` is ``None`` return d[``g1``.lower()]

Comment: _"Could I still use m.group?"_ I don't understand. ``ripl()`` is a function that successively receives  all the MatchObjects found by the regex along the analyzed text. ``ma`` isn't a string, it is a MatchObject. You must read the doc. Then, inside the function, all is possible by exploiting the information contained in the MatchObject groups() and other methods (span, etc).