# How do I reverse regex substitution?

Tags: python, regex

Going back to this example,

[Having trouble dealing with similar characters to print different things using regex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177532/having-trouble-dealing-with-similar-characters-to-print-different-things-using-r)

I was wondering how would I reverse the regex substitution I did and just print out the original text ?

That is, so if I have

```
text = "This is my first regex python example yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd"
```

as my original text, then it's output would be:

```
re.sub text = "tookhookisook isook mookyook fookirooksooktook pookyooktookhookonook..."
```

And then I want that output to be converted back to the original text.

How do I do that?

Comment: It's impossible to do, since in the original text there is an uppercased letter in "This" and the substitution of this word gives "tookhookisook" according to the second string you show here. That means that the substitution from 1 to 2 isn't exactly the one whose I gave the code in the other post: to make "T" becoming "t", you must use ``lower()`` method in the replacement drawback function. So doing, the info of uppercased letters is lost. It is impossible to say which letters in the string 2 are coming from uppercased ones in string 1.

Comment: Ohhhh you bring up a very good point! For argument's sake, what if the case didn't matter, could I still convert it back to the original string (case insensitive?)

Comment: As I was sure you would ask this question after having read my comment, I was already working on this problem. :)

Comment: Thank you! Regex are too interesting. Having too much fun learning what I can and what I can't do in Regex. I will play around with some of your code and see if I can figure out some other things about it. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Could you think to vote and maybe accept my answers if they are of interest for you ? - By the way, see the ``lastindex`` attribute of a MatchObject in the documentation, it's sometimes very interesting to use instead of numbering of groups.

Comment: Will do. Sorry about that and yeah, I'll check out the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this works:

```
import re 

tu = ('This is my first regex python example '
      'yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd',

      'bbbiirdd',

      'fookirooksooktook',

      'crrsciencezxxxxxscienceokjjsciencq')

reg   = re.compile(r'([bcdfghj-np-tv-z])(\1?)')
dereg = re.compile('science([^aeiou])|([^aeiou])ook')

def Frepl(ma):
    g1,g2 = ma.groups()
    if g2:  return 'science' + g2
    else:   return g1 + 'ook'

def Fderepl(ma):
    g = ma.group(2)
    if g:  return g
    else:  return 2*ma.group(1)

for strt in tu:
    resu =   reg.sub(Frepl  , strt)
    bakk = dereg.sub(Fderepl, resu)
    print ('----------------------------------\n'
           'strt = %s\n'    'resu == %s\n'
           'bakk == %s\n'   'bakk == start : %s'
           % (strt, resu, bakk, bakk==strt))
```

#### Edit

First, I updated the above code: I eliminated the `re.I` flag. It was capturing portions like 'dD' as a repeated letter. so it was transformed to 'scienceD', then back to 'DD'

Secondly, I extended the code with a dictionary.
Instead of replacing a letter with letter+'ook', it replaces according to the letter.
For example, I choosed to replace 'b' with 'BAR', 'c' with 'CORE'.... I put the values of the dictionary uppercased, to have a better view of the result. It may in fact be anything else.
The programs takes care of the case. I put only 'T','Y','X' in the dictionary, it's just for essay.

```
import re 

d = {'b':'BAR','c':'CORE','d':'DEAD','f':'FAN',
     'g':'GO','h':'HHH','j':'JIU','k':'KOAN',
     'l':'LOW','m':'MY','n':'NERD','p':'PI',
     'q':'QIM','r':'ROAR','s':'SING','t':'TIP',
     'v':'VIEW','w':'WAVE','x':'XOR',
     'y':'YEAR','z':'ZOO',
     'T':'tears','Y':'yearling','X':'xylophone'}

ded = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.iteritems())
print ded

tu = ('This is my first regex python example '
       'Yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd',

      'bbbiirdd',

      'fookirooksooktook',

      'crrsciencezxxxxxXscienceokjjsciencq')

reg   = re.compile(r'([bcdfghj-np-tv-zBCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z])(\1?)')

othergr = '|'.join(ded.keys())
dereg = re.compile('science([^aeiouAEIOU])|(%s)' % othergr)

def Frepl(ma, d=d):
    g1,g2 = ma.groups()
    if g2:  return 'science' + g2
    else:   return d[g1]

def Fderepl(ma,ded=ded):
    g = ma.group(2)
    if g:  return ded[g]
    else:  return 2*ma.group(1)

for strt in tu:
    resu =   reg.sub(Frepl  , strt)
    bakk = dereg.sub(Fderepl, resu)
    print ('----------------------------------\n'
           'strt = %s\n'    'resu == %s\n'
           'bakk == %s\n'   'bakk == start : %s'
           % (strt, resu, bakk, bakk==strt))
```

result

```
----------------------------------
strt = This is my first regex python example Yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd
resu == tearsHHHiSING iSING MYYEAR FANiROARSINGTIP ROAReGOeXOR PIYEARTIPHHHoNERD eXORaMYPILOWe yearlingaHHHooa YEARaHHHoouuee sciencebBARiiROARscienced
bakk == This is my first regex python example Yahooa yahoouuee bbbiirdd
bakk == start : True
----------------------------------
strt = bbbiirdd
resu == sciencebBARiiROARscienced
bakk == bbbiirdd
bakk == start : True
----------------------------------
strt = fookirooksooktook
resu == FANooKOANiROARooKOANSINGooKOANTIPooKOAN
bakk == fookirooksooktook
bakk == start : True
----------------------------------
strt = crrsciencezxxxxxXscienceokjjsciencq
resu == COREsciencerSINGCOREieNERDCOREeZOOsciencexsciencexXORxylophoneSINGCOREieNERDCOREeoKOANsciencejSINGCOREieNERDCOREQIM
bakk == crrsciencezxxxxxXscienceokjjsciencq
bakk == start : True
```

Comment: You are fantastic and utterly nuts in a good way :D Thank you, I'll be working my way through bits of this!

Comment: Regex field isn't the field in which I am the more ignorant, it's true, but I consider I know 15 % about them. And I know only 1 or 2 % of Python galaxy. 'fantastic' appears to me an undue adjective.

Answer (score 4):

Python strings are immutable. You haven't *changed* the original, only created a new string. Just keep a reference to the original.

**Edit**
By immutable, I mean that their actual value is frozen once create.

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> s[0]
'a'
>>> s[1] = 'd'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    s[1] = 'd'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

In the example above I can have the variable `s` reference another object, but the string I assigned to it is constant. So when you do `s.replace()`, the result is a *new* string, and the original is unchanged.

```
>>> s.replace ('a', 'd')
'dbc'
>>> s
'abc'
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, He'll have to clarify that. Not to mention keeping a reference also works when the reverse substitution is impossible :)

Comment: I don't want a reference to the original string because I want to make sure what I translated/substituted is correct. So my plan is to use re.sub to take the original string, substitute it, then reverse the substitution or substitute it again to make the original string and write a test to check if the 2nd original string makes the 1st original string.

Comment: Wait, what you mean by immutable? Can you explain what you mean by reference to the original? Sorry for the confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "convert" a regex substitution backwards in Python or any other regex implementation.

That is simply because the substitution is a one-way street that returns a new string, and there is no magical reverse function

Here is an illustration using string.replace()  :

```
original_string = 'abc'
newstring = original_string.replace('a','b')
'bbc'
```

converting newstring into 'abc' wouldn't just be substituting 'b' for 'a'.  you can't create a "reverse" regex out of any given regex.  if we replaced 'b' with 'a' in this example, the string would be 'aac' -- not bbc.

the regex functions work the same was as string.replace -- they return a new string.  they don't return an object that knows the exact state of every regex replacement.

you have two options to do whatever it is you want to do:

1-  create a custom class that represents a string and tracks an (infinite?) number of regular expression operations, allowing you to create a diff between each state.

2- do what everyone else does, and what many people here suggest: you simply need to stash the original string ( or a copy of it ) off to the side.

( this is an effort to simplify the answer from @StoryTeller )